# RAD 8.5 XPath view

Tags: java, eclipse, ibm-rad

We're testing out RAD 8.5 and I'm having some trouble with a new XML Perspective:

When I open the XML Perspective, I the source in the main window, the Outline View on the upper right, and the Templates view (empty) on the lower right. And that's *all* I get.

The last time I used this perspective with a standard Eclipse installation (I think it was 3.6), there was also an XPath View on the lower left where I could test XPath expressions on the source, and the Templates view actually had snippets of common XPath expressions (I think). Something like this:

[image]

Is there a way to get the XPath view into RAD 8.5? I tried looking under "Show View -> Other..." but I couldn't find this view. I'm guessing that we missed a feature during installation that contained this view, but I have no idea what it was. Does anyone know what feature I should install to get this view working?

Answer (score -1):

Have You tried to open menu:

```
Window > Show View > Outline
```

?

Comment: That shows the document outline view. I am specifically trying to use the XPath Navigator view, as seen in the Eclipse screen shot. This view does not appear to be available in RAD 8.5, or maybe I just haven't installed the correct feature. That's what I'm asking: Is this view available, and if so, what feature should I install so that I can use it?

Comment: Thought the Outline view could be the answer (workaround) for your problem, but I was wrong.